# Static vs dynamic provisioning of configs

Tags: configuration, chef-infra, consul

I am trying to find a right config management tool for a new project. I came across Consule. Before I come to my question I would like to quote what consul page says:

> Static configuration that may be provided by configuration management tools can be moved into the dynamic key/value store. This allows application configuration to be updated without a slow convergence run.

It also says:

> That said, Consul is not a replacement for configuration management tools. These tools are still critical to set up applications, including Consul itself. Static provisioning is best managed by existing tools while dynamic state and discovery is better managed by Consul.

*Source: https://www.consul.io/intro/vs/chef-puppet.html*

My understanding is consul is a dynamic config management tool and it's fast. But my question is what is how is it different from static config management tools like chef?

**Most importantly when to chose what ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It't not really so much about fast or slow. The problem with Chef/Ansible/Puppet/etc. is that these systems usually run periodically, e.g. every 30 minutes.

So if one node changes (or is added/deleted), it may take up to 30 minutes until all other nodes notice this (be it application servers and database servers that find each other).

Consul (maybe with [consul-template](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-template)) is much faster, kind of immediate, here. All connected notes are notified that something changed. However, it does not provide the primitives of the above-mentioned config management tools.

So the combination of both is also valid. Chef/Puppet/Ansible/etc. to install packages and write most of the config, plus Consul (or etcd) for the fast-moving parts.

Answer (score 1):

here's my 0.05$ on this issue:
If you have *dynamic* infrastructure on some cloud - meaning servers that are created and destroyed occasionally ("ephemeral servers"), usually to meet some changing load, then consul is a great tool: these servers can be booted up and read their config from consul at startup time.

Ideally, in this use case you would be launching a pre-baked server that you customized to your needs. For example, your server would need to have consul on it when its booted. You could use Ansible to pre-bake consul into the server.

so the process is this:

1. you create a template for your servers with all the goodies you need (libraries, apps, consul, whatever). You could use Ansible to do so. This gets done just once (per template)
2. you use your cloud to launch these templates - and when they start,the consul client on them gets some additional configuration values from the Consul cluster (this happens every time a server gets launched).